# ubuntu server 18.04 запуск Selenium python для телеграм бота

Tags: python, ubuntu, selenium, telegram

Установлена система Ubuntu server 18.06 i386 на старенький нетбук в котором слабый проц и 2 гб оперативной памяти. Хотел на нем запустить телеграм бота. Все было бы нормально пока мне не понадобился селениум. Я понимаю что оно говорит что не может найти драйвер для 32х битной ubuntu server. Как выйти из этой ситуации. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70886717/chromedriver-for-linux32-does-not-exist-python-selenium-chromedriver попробуйте

Comment: driver_path = "/usr/bin/chromedriver"
Нету такой папки... все что там прописано, я сделал даже отдельный файлик для проверки..
 selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/home.
Есть chromium-browser в папке /usr/bin/ но chromedriver нету.

Comment: а пробовали качать архив по ссылке ? создать любую папку и расокавать туда архив с драйвером. и указать к ней путь ?

Comment: Так драйвер же 64х.... Скачать с https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads

Comment: точно, туплю с утра )

Comment: Там только chromedriver_linux64.zip

Comment: Я так полагаю что врятли такой вариант пройдет. Нужно использовать FireFox.

Comment: Я бы переставил на 64 бита. Проц 64-х битный, не вижу преград.

Comment: Нетбук старенький на него 64х не ставиться... Поэтому и мучаюсь с 32х